# Person name placeholder in your country/region/language

Tags: labels, team-building, globalization

Fun one related to working remotely: What are typical equivalents for name placeholders like Joe Doe in your region? Especially Russia, India, Latin America and more examples from English. But honestly – I am curious for examples from other areas as well.

Comment: Take a look at this article. It can help you to find some placeholders: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_placeholder_names_by_language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw [this blog post](http://www.babynamewizard.com/archives/2014/6/the-names-of-the-nameless-move-over-john-doe-and-john-q-public) a little while ago. The main article focuses on American placeholder names, but there are some fascinating international examples in the comments section.

EDIT:

Just found that she did [a post about the international ones](http://www.babynamewizard.com/archives/2014/7/nobodies-abroad-joe-schmo-meet-otto-normalverbraucher) too.